# Time and date difference in 2 cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I am having Excel with Date time stamp at random row in B Column, 
Ex: Where in between cell are Empty ( `B2`, `B3`..etc).

```
B1 :  15:13:48:335 2014/08/06
B27:  15:13:55:955 2014/08/06
B31:  15:14:16:005 2014/08/06 ...
```

I need to find the time difference between 2 consecutive entries Ex: `B21-B1` and `B31-B27` and so on.

Comment: Are those actual datetimes or just text that looks like a datetime? Are the values right or left aligned in the cells?

Comment: @Jeeped: i am getting these values from text .txt file, so it just look like date and time  :(

Comment: Use `=ISNUMBER(B1)` to determine if the cell is numeric/date. Excel may have converted it to a date. A date value is numeric; same thing.

Comment: Thanks @D_Bester, =ISNUMBER(B1) is FALSE so i am trying for =LARGE(B:B, 1)-LARGE(B:B, 2), but it says #NUM Error.

Comment: If it is not numeric then use `=VALUE(B1)` to convert to a number then use cell format to display date. Then your formulas should work.

Comment: Fix your data first. Then worry about manipulating the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values you've shown are actual datetimes, then they are numbers that seem to grow progressively larger as the rows increase.

To get the difference from B1 to B27,

```
=LARGE(B:B, 2)-LARGE(B:B, 3)
```

Format the result as time in any way you prefer.

For the difference from B27 to B31,

```
=LARGE(B:B, 1)-LARGE(B:B, 2)
```

When datetimes are actual datetimes and not text, the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) can be used just like any other number.

If your values in column B are text, start by reverting them to proper datetimes. Use something like the following,

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(B1, 5)&"/"&MID(B1, 14, 4))+TIMEVALUE(LEFT(B1, 8)&"."&MID(B1, 10,3))
```

Correct your data first; then worry about manipulating the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If the cells propreties are correct, Excel should be able do compute a difference between them without any problem.

Both of the cells containing the dates must be set with Date/Hour format, the cell containing the result of the difference can be (for instance) set to Standard. Then the difference will be a number (integer or float). For instance :

- If the result is 3, it means 3 days, multiply it by 24 to have the
  number of hours.
- If the result is 3,6667, the integer part gives you
  the number of full days, the float part gives you the number of
  hours. 0.6667*24 = 16 hours.

Hope it helped