# Calculating date difference in days - excel

Tags: excel

I have already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004042/time-and-date-difference-in-2-cells-in-excel) but didn't have a clue on how it can help me out here. I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates which are in format - MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

e.g.

```
Data Creation(COLA1)    Data Closure(COL B1)       Number(COL C1) of Days
16/05/2016 19:58:02     23/05/2016 19:38:41                 X
```

I want a formula for number of days(X) here.

**Excel Version - 2010**

Comment: Excel stores dates as decimal numbers, where the integer part represents the number of days since `31 Dec 1899` and the fractional part represents the time (fraction of a day).  So it is a matter of simple subtraction and then just format as a number.  Depending on how you want to treat the fractional portion, you may need to either Round or Truncate.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/977610/in-excel-2010-how-can-i-subtract-two-times-when-i-also-have-the-date-in-the-cel).
You need only to change from seconds to days

Comment: That works only if the dates in both columns are same

Answer (score 0):

I would use a personalized number format (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) and then just round up the difference between dates.

[image: Difference between two dates in days]

For example here DIFFERENCE = ROUNDUP((DATE1-DATE2);0)

Comment: Do I need to keep **(** and **)** in the format? I am trying but its not working

Comment: @Techidiot Nope, no brackets. I just change it through the GUI. Mine is in spanish but I guess it's something like Number -> Personalized/Custom -> Type and there you type the format: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. The difference cell has no format (general)

Comment: Still not working. Don't we need to convert to number while doing DATE1-DATE?

Comment: @Techidiot I don't think so. At least I don't. Maybe it depend's on what version are you using? It works for me just the way I put there.

Comment: Yes. Becuase, I am following the steps but it just doesn't work and shows #VALUE! in the resultant column

Comment: Then I recommend you put the version you are using in the question so people can help more efficiently than me.

Comment: Updated now. Thanks.